# find the number of occurences and add it next to the pattern

Tags: linux, awk, sed, tags, find-occurrences

I have several files in a directory and in some of them, some patterns occur multiple times. For example

Contents of file "`8_list`":

```
Spiroplasma_taiwanense 
Spiroplasma_diminutum 
Spiroplasma_apis 
Spiroplasma_sabaudiense 
Spiroplasma_taiwanense 
Spiroplasma_diminutum 
Spiroplasma_taiwanense 
EntAcro10
EntAcro10
Spiroplasma_apis 
Spiroplasma_culicicola 
Spiroplasma_sabaudiense 
Spiroplasma_diminutum 
Spiroplasma_sabaudiense 
Spiroplasma_sabaudiense 
Spiroplasma_sabaudiense 
Spiroplasma_apis 
Spiroplasma_culicicola 
Spiroplasma_culicicola 
Spiroplasma_culicicola 
Spiroplasma_culicicola 
Spiroplasma_diminutum 
Spiroplasma_culicicola 
Spiroplasma_culicicola 
EntAcro1
```

and contents of file "`574_list`"

```
Mesoplasma_florum_l1
Spiroplasma_sabaudiense 
Mesoplasma_florum_w37
EntAcro1
```

all files have a single column. 
What I want to do is within each file find the identical patterns and then add a number next to it describing the occurrence. For example, in file "`8_list`" if `Spiroplasma_culicicola` occurs 7 times, then next to the first occurrence, it should write `Spiroplasma_culicicola_1`,
next to the second occurrence `Spiroplasma_culicicola_2`
next to the third occurrence `Spiroplasma_culicicola_3`
etc etc

I tried to do it with `sed` by looking for each pattern individually

```
sed -z 's/Spiroplasma_culicicola/Spiroplasma_culicicola_2/2'
```

but I was wondering if there is an easier way in order to do it for all my files and all patterns in a given directory

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good task for such nice tool as `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(" ", "", $0); a[$0]++; print $0"_"a[$0]}' 8_list
```

`gsub(" ", "", $0);` - replaces trailing space at the end of the line

`a[$0]++;` - incrementing the number of occurrences of each pattern(column value) treating a column value as an array key

---

The output:

```
Spiroplasma_taiwanense_1
Spiroplasma_diminutum_1
Spiroplasma_apis_1
Spiroplasma_sabaudiense_1
Spiroplasma_taiwanense_2
Spiroplasma_diminutum_2
Spiroplasma_taiwanense_3
EntAcro10_1
EntAcro10_2
Spiroplasma_apis_2
Spiroplasma_culicicola_1
Spiroplasma_sabaudiense_2
Spiroplasma_diminutum_3
Spiroplasma_sabaudiense_3
Spiroplasma_sabaudiense_4
Spiroplasma_sabaudiense_5
Spiroplasma_apis_3
Spiroplasma_culicicola_2
Spiroplasma_culicicola_3
Spiroplasma_culicicola_4
Spiroplasma_culicicola_5
Spiroplasma_diminutum_4
Spiroplasma_culicicola_6
Spiroplasma_culicicola_7
EntAcro1_1
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot @RomanPerekhrest! That is exactly what I was looking for! Can I ask one more thing; what if I wanted to search for specific patterns and add only to them a tag showing the number of occurrences? For example lets say that in the above file I only want to do that for the "taiwanense" pattern...

Comment: @Panos, welcome. Your new requirement can definitely be presented as a new SO question. After it was posted you can inform me and I'll help you

Comment: Thanks! Question posted as new thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928227/using-awk-to-find-pattern-if-line-starts-with-and-add-at-the-end-of-it-the-n